# Expressing a vector as a linear combination of others

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

I was trying to solve this question:
Let $a=(2,-5,3)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Express it as a linear combination of vectors 
\begin{align}
e_1&=(1,-3,2) \\ e_2&=(2,-4,-1)\\ e_3 &=(1,-5,7)
\end{align} 
Solution: 
$$(2,-5,3)=a(1,-3,2)+b(2,-4,-1)+c(1,-5,7)$$
therefore,
\begin{align}
a+2b+c&=2 \\
3a+4b+5c&=5 \\
2a-c+7c&=3
\end{align}
Applying row operations:
$a+2b+c=2$,    $ 2b-2c=1$   $ -5b+5c=-1$
The last two equations are coming out to be parallel. What does this imply? Also, Can that vector now be expressed as a linear combination of other Vectors?

Comment: This means that the system is inconsistent due to the linear dependence of the vectors. There is no linear combination of $e_1$, $e_2$, or $e_3$ that can make $a$. Imagine the case where all your vectors only lie on the xy plane. Could any linear combination create a vector pointing in the z-direction?

Answer (score 1):

As it is clear the vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are not linear independent so their
dont make a basis for $R^3$. So we can not express any vector in $\mathbb R^3$ as linear combination of these vectors.
But you can express in vector in $\mathbb R^3$ as linear combination of elements of any basis such as $$e_1=(1,0,0),e_2+(0,1,0),e_3=(0,0,1)$$ and any other basis of $R^3$.

Comment: Do you mean “every vector” instead of “any vector?”

Comment: yes i mean every vector